# Dimensions of EM potential/field tensor components in curvilinear coordinates

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, dimensional-analysis

According to this resource on [Maxwell theory in curved spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations_in_curved_spacetime), the form of the field strength tensor is independent of the choice of coordinates:
$$F_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$$
regardless of the choice of coordinates $x^\mu$. However, in many coordinate systems the coordinates chosen do not have the same dimension: for example, in cylindrical polar coordinates $(r, \theta, z)$, $r$ and $z$ have dimensions of length whilst $\theta$ is dimensionless.

This means that in order for $F_{\mu \nu}$ to be a meaningful number, the components of $A_\mu$ must generally have different dimension: in cylindrical polars $A_\theta$ must have dimensions of $[\text{length}] A_r$. Similarly the components of $F_{\mu \nu}$ must also have different dimension. Is it "allowed" to have a vector of mixed dimension? It seems like this must be the case, but such a concept makes me feel a little uneasy.

For clarification, the question is as follows: does formulating Maxwell theory in a general coordinate system imply that the vector and field tensor components have different dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as there is no need a set of  coordinates all to have the same dimensions, there is no need for the *components* of a tensor to have the same dimensions. The tensor as an object itself, however, has a well defined dimension. For example: if $V$ is a voltage then the electric field ${\bf E}=-\nabla V$ has components   $E_\mu=- \partial_\mu V$. With the $(x^1,x^2,x^3)$ being  spherical polars $(r,\theta,\phi)$, the field ${\bf E}$  will have radial component with units of volts per meter while the other two components are in units of volts per radian.  The associated covariant vector (a 1-form)   is 
$$
dV= (\partial_\mu V) dx^\mu \in T^*({\mathbb R}^3)
$$
where the $dx^\mu$ are the basis elements of the cotangent space.  The covariant vector $dV$ itself has units of volts because the dimensions of the basis vector $dx^\mu$ compensate for those of the components. Similarly components of a contravariant vector such as a velocity might be meters per second or radians per second, but the velocity vector 
$$
{\bf v}= v^\mu \partial_\mu\in T({\mathbb R}^3)
$$
has units of inverse seconds ---  i.e. dimension [T]$^{-1}$. Here the $\partial_\mu$ are the basis vectors of the tangent space, and are dual to the $dx^\mu$ in that $dx^\mu(\partial_\nu)= \delta^\mu_\nu$.

The basic  lesson is that a tensor, considered as as an element of a tensor space, has  a single  dimension, but its individual components do not.  It is therefore always best to include the basis elements when thinking about tensors. Many notational problems in physics go away when we do this.

Comment: Thank you, this cleared things up.